# Issue with transferring of developer certificate and Provisioning Profile under Xcode

Tags: iphone

I am trying transfer my developer certificate under the keychain to someone. I exported the item.   And also send him the provisioning profile which includes his device ID. 
He installed my certificate to his keychain and also the provisioning profile to his xcode.
However, The provisioning profile under his xcode complains of there's no Valid signing Identity. Well I already sent him the certificate.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to export the matching private key with the Developer Certificate, you can select both the private key and Certificate and export at the same time.

Comment: Some certificates don't have a key underneath.

Comment: Well whatever key was used to create the certificate should be in the keychain.

Comment: I tried that, selecting both the cert and its private key (find them grouped in "Keychain Access"), and exported them as as p12. Still, when importing these on the other Mac, Xcode there still says that it has no valid signing identity. I eventually found the solution here, where it explains how to use the Export function of the "Teams" in Xcode's Organizer: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57059

Answer (score 0):

Does he have multiple certificates with the same name in his keychain? In which case he may have to delete the one that is not applicable for this profile when he is trying to build the app (he can reinstall the deleted certificate later). Also, ask him to delete and reinstall the profile. Is there any more information he is getting with the error?

Comment: No, only that particular name.  Each certificate has a unique name. He hasn't build any app, just looking at the provisioning profile under organizer, and there's yellow warning as no valid signing identity.

Comment: I meant multiple certificates with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the development & distribution certificates that you provided, you also need to export your private key as a *.p12 file.  When he is importing this elements into the Keychain application ensure he selects the "login" keychain.